# Where's the TYPE command in ServiceStack.Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisNativeClient but this interface doesn't include the TYPE command. Why? How can I access this functionality?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ServiceStack.Redis, but did you try downloading its source code and run a quick Find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient contains a 'Type' method and a 'GetEntryType' method (which returns an enum instead of string). These methods are just missing from the interface (IRedisNativeClient)